# How to show selected region of cube in opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a cube drawn in opengl android. Now, when I move finger on that cube, i have to show selected region by finger on that cube.

Comment: Can we put any layer on selected region e.g. transparent color on selected region? How?